# numbers and strings in array python

Tags: python-2.7

What I am trying to do is pull the numbers from the array and then have it print **** for the number in the array. If its not a number it will then pull the first letter of the string and print that times the length of the array. Im new to python and I have been looking all over to find how to do this. Appricate any help.

```
x = [4, "Tom", 1, "Michael", 5, 7, "Jimmy Smith"]

for i in x:
    if "a number":
        print "*" * i
    else:
         print str[:1] .lower() * len(str)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't know what "a number" means.

```
if "a number":
```

searches for a string that looks like "a number". The only way I know (of which there are likely more) is to use the function

```
if type(i) == <class 'int'> : 
    print("*" * i)
```

This asks the interpreter what the type of i is () and checks to see if that's the same as what you're looking for (==).

Comment: Can i do the same thing using str ie else: type(i) == str:
     print()

Comment: not quite - the else: function doesn't accept input. You have to instead use an elif command, short for else if. The code would look like `elif type(i) == <class 'str'> :`

Comment: elif type(i) == <class 'str'> :
        print(test)  this trows an error

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [4, "Tom", 1, "Michael", 5, 7, "Jimmy Smith"]

for i in range(0,len(x),1):
    if isinstance(x[i], (int, long, float, complex)):
        print("*"*x[i])
    else:
        print(x[i][:1].lower() + "*" + str(len(x[i])))
```

Comment: 5 starts i want start the time the number in the array and the else is to be lower case time length

Comment: Ah ok. number times stars. Corrected the solution to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

The full answer to the question.

```
x = [4, "Tom", 1, "Michael", 5, 7, "Jimmy Smith"]

for i in x:
    if type(i) == int : 
        print("*" * i)
    elif type(i) == str:
        print i[:1].lower() * len(i)
```